# Stack Overflow's job stats

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, statistics

[Stack Overflow career](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/)'s page has been moved to [Stack Overflow jobs.](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?t=c&r=home)

In the previous version I could see some minimal stats on the right, such has *"search hits"*, *"views by employers"* and so on... are they gone?